# Move a UIView's superview by setting its center property

Tags: ios, uiview, positioning, cgaffinetransform

I have a very strange problem. I trying to rotate and move a UIView's superview manually in `viewDidAppear` like so:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // ...

    [self.view.superview setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2)];
    [self.view.superview setCenter:CGPointMake(100, 200)]; // (100, 200) is toy value

    // ...
}
```

For some reason, the rotation is applied correctly but the superview's center (i.e. position) is not moved at all. I've also tried setting the transform to a `CGAffineTransform` that's a combination of a rotation + translation (or just a translation alone), and that won't move the superview either.

If it makes a difference, `self.view.superview` is the top-most view (i.e. `self.view.superview.superview` is `nil`).

Am I missing something very simple here?

Edit: nielsbot's comment was correct in that putting it in viewDidLoad worked, but by then, the view has already appeared so there's a flicker where it snaps to the new location. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Try it in `viewDidAppear`--your code says `viewWillAppear`. It's possible some layout code might run after *will appear* and undo your changes.

Comment: First, make clear wht u want to say by " the rotation is applied correctly but the superview is not moved at all"??

Comment: @nielsbot That worked, but there's a flicker because it first shows the view, the moves it there afterwards. Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the bounds of the view so:

```
[self.view.superview setBounds:CGRectMake(x,y,self.view.superview.width,self.view.superview.height)];
```

This should move your view to the x,y position you give him 
But of course this is not the center

The center just represents a special point that is for example used for rotations

Comment: I believe that once I set a transform on the view, the frame is no longer valid: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW3

Comment: Thats correct the top left corner (origin) of the frame moves with transform, if you don't want to calculate a new point for the frame use the bounds origin